# How to hide a Model property for certain users?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

I am building an API that will serve users with different administration levels (roles)

I have the following model (redacted for brevity)

```
public class Job
{
    public Guid JobId { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string CommentsAdmins { get; set; }
}
```

When an admin user calls the API controller, I want the API to return the entire model above. But when a regular user calls the API, I want the model to return the same model, minus `CommentsAdmins`

```
public class Job
{
    public Guid JobId { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

I'm not comfortable to use a nullable `string?` because I believe that's a dirty way to do it. Also I don't want the field to be visible in my mobile app code, which may be publicly visible if somebody tries to decompile the mobile app binaries.

Additionally, creating multiple models for multiple user levels doesn't feel intuitive as well.

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: If you don't want to use a second model without that property and you don't want to use the same model with that property nulled then what you want is impossible. Have a nice day.

Comment: If you don't want the field to be in the code so that it can't be seen when decompiled is it correct to assume that your mobile app will not have any users with permissions where they'd be able to see the field?

Comment: @Logarr The mobile app will have users with lower permission levels, and they're not allowed to see the `CommentsAdmins` field. This is obviously one of the instances, I have other models in the API that have properties with financial information, such as `cost` or `profit` which I don't want to have them included in the API response for users with lower permissions.

Comment: I don't think It is possible to use one model show different properties based on user.

Comment: @John Using a second model means there will duplicates of the same code, which makes it a lot more cumbersome to debug and in case of any change, the possibility of forgetting to change one of the model's redacted copies will be higher. Additionally, this method requires copying object values to the redacted models for every organizational role level. Is this really the only way?

Comment: Why would there be duplicate code? One model class would inherit the other and all its members.